# Why markdown ignores single line break?

Tags: markdown

I know the solution to make single line break. I just want to know the reason.

when I input this,

```markdown
line1
line2
```

preview of this md file is

```
line1line2
```

Why? is single line break looking bad or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Chris's answer provides the reasons mentioned in the documentation. However, to understand why those decisions were made, we need to consider the situation at the time. Text editors have changed and become much more sophisticated since Markdown was created. As an example, note the [documentation](https://s3.amazonaws.com/BBSW-download/BBEdit_13.5.7_User_Manual.pdf) (PDF) for [BBEdit](https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/index.html), the text editor which is a favorite of the creator of Markdown (as I understand it, he actually worked for the company as a software developer before creating Markdown).

At the bottom of page 110 of the documentation, we find this note:

> Users of very old versions of BBEdit or BBEdit Lite will note that the Wrap while Typing option (which hard-wrapped text automatically by inserting a Return when you reach the right margin) has been relegated to the dustbin of history. It has been superseded by soft wrapping.

Back when Markdown was created, text editors did not offer soft wrapping as a feature. Instead, they simulated soft wrapping by "automatically" inserting hard line breaks. Less sophisticated editors actually required users to manually insert the heard lines breaks and offered no soft wrapping at all. Therefore, if Markdown were to preserve those hard line breaks, it would result in something different from what was intended by the document author.

Markdown was simply never updated to match current common behaviors of text editors. In fact, some users still prefer that way of working and still customize their text editors to work that way. They still get to enjoy the same behavior of Markdown.

By the way, I suggest reading through the 5 or so pages of BBEdit's manual explaining all of the text wrapping options. There are a lot of different ways of working and we should never assume that all people work the same way as we do. If only every text editor offered such a rich set of text wrapping features.

Comment: Text editors could certainly word-wrap in 2004, when Markdown was created. Notepad [in Windows 3.0](https://www.pcjs.org/software/pcx86/sys/windows/3.00/) would do that back in 1990, the year HTML was created: another mark-up language that ignores hard line breaks. This answer is speculative and anachronistic.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what this is supposed to mean. Soft word wrap has been standard in word processors since the early '80s at *least,* and was universal in every text editor I've seen by the mid-'90s. Markdown came out in 2004.

You're saying the Markdown developer decided to include a mandatory workaround for a shortcoming of a text editor version that was obsolete long before Markdown's release? And no one has ever fixed it? That's bizarre. I mean, I can *believe* it, but it's still bizarre.

Answer (score 3):

So the Markdown source, which [is intended to be as readable as possible](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), can be nicely formatted.

Quoting [the documentation](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p):

> Yes, this takes a tad more effort to create a `<br />`, but a simplistic "every line break is a `<br />`" rule wouldn’t work for Markdown. Markdown’s email-style [blockquoting](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#blockquote) and multi-paragraph [list items](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list) work best — and look better — when you format them with hard breaks.

Note that you can force a line break (`<br>`) if you end your `line1` with two or more spaces:

line1
line2

A blank line actually creates a new paragraph.